# Selenide - How to handle gmail pop up in chrome

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver, selenide

I am trying to switch to a Gmail login popup that appears on clicking a button on my chrome. When I do a driver getWindowHandles(), it shows only one window - the parent. Also I noticed in the taskbar that the popup that opens has a google/gmail icon instead of chrome browser icon which is why I am assuming that the Webdriver does not count it as a second open "chrome" window, but instead a different one altogether.

So far I have tried everything on the driver methods

`driver.switchTo().window(1 or 0)`

Any suggestions would be helpful!!

Answer (score 0):

```
driver.switchTo().alert().anyMethod
```

can be used.

Comment: it is not an alert, and anyway I tried it too, doesnt work

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49624260/how-to-handle-log-in-with-google-popup-window-using-selenium-webdriver    Check this out.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, why are you using driver. with Selenide? Selenide has a static WebDriver call - getWebDriver()  (if really needed) with the next import `import static com.codeborne.selenide.WebDriverRunner.getWebDriver;`

From your quesiton, it is not clear what you want - either its pop up that appears after clicking or you want to switch to another chrome tab window?

If its a pop up alert, then the next code should help (to accept it for example):

```
getWebDriver().switchTo().alert().accept();
```

If you want to open a tab or focus on it:

```
switchTo().window(1);
```